# "Map Range" node equivalent for Material nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor, particles

I would like to use the age of particles to effect the color of a material, however the [*Particle Info* node returns the age of the particles in frames](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Particle_Info) so the values are greater than one. (which makes the [*ColorRamp*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Types/Convertor#ColorRamp_Node) node ineffective as it works in the 0-1 range.)

[image: Image of my node setup]

So I need to convert the *Age* value to the 0-1 range (As you would with the *Map Range*/[*Map Value node*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Windows/Nodes/Composite#Map_Value)) but with *Material nodes* instead of *Composite nodes*.
Is this possible?

Comment: dude, how did you figure out the output was in frames?? got that exact question up here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/how-to-view-value-of-node-output

Comment: @krivar it says so on the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Particle_Info) ;)
That's a good question though, you might want to consider generalizing it to be something like "is it possible to view values outputted by node as numbers?" I have wondered that too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Math node set to multiply:

- on top put `1.0 / max age`  <-- this you can precalculate
- in the second socket connect `age`

=  `0....1`

**or**, Use two Math nodes. Useful for if your `max age` is the same as `lifetime` of the particle. This way you can also deal with a dynamically changing particle lifetime.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just *Divide* the *Age* by the *Lifetime*? You would have a [ParticleInfo] node and a [Divide] node, and [ParticleInfo:Age] -> [Divide:TopValue], [ParticleInfo:Lifetime] -> [Divide:BottomValue].