# How do I get particles to change color over time?

Tags: animation, materials, texturing, particles

I saw a conversation on BlenderArtist.org where someone posted a node setup that supposedly would change the color of particles over time based on the Particle Info node's Index value. This is the graphic they posted:

[image]

However, when I tried to duplicate this effect, the particles don't change color over time.

[image]

Here is the [original conversation](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?331168-Particle-ID-and-Driver-to-use-as-counter&p=2605194&viewfull=1#post2605194)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1910/599

Comment: i know this conversation is old, but i wanted to link a good video for everyone that, as me, still hit these conversations.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HGb7Ce1yLU

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### **Two Techniques to Have Particles Change Color Over Time**

I discovered two ways to have particles change color over time, but they both start the same way:

1. First, create an object to be the particles for the particle system. I used a sphere in the videos below.
2. Create an object (I used a plane) and add a particle system to it with these settings:

   - In the Emission section for the videos below, I have:
     Number = 1000
     Start = 1
     End = 200
     Lifetime = 200
   - In the Velocity section, set Normal to a desired value. I used 7.0 in the videos below.
   - In the Render section, select Object and then for Dupli Object select the object you made for the particles in step 1.
3. Now add a material to the particle object. Here is where I discovered two different node tree configurations to create two different effects:

### **Effect #1: Each particle is a different color & stays that color over it's entire lifetime**

[image]

For this technique the node tree for the particle object's material is made like this:

[image]

**NOTE:** For this effects, the Divide node's Value must be set to the number of particles in the particle system (here, it's 1000)

This technique was developed by [kubo](http://blenderartists.org/forum/member.php?143873-kubo) on [BlenderArtists.org](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?331168-Particle-ID-and-Driver-to-use-as-counter).

### **Effect #2: All particles change color over the course of their lifetime**

[image]

This is the node tree for this technique:

[image]

**NOTE:** For this effects, the Divide node's Value is set to a low number (here, it's 50), not to the number of particles

This technique was developed by [Vader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1476/vader) and [Greg Zaal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/9/greg-zaal) here on StackExchange.

### **Previewing the Effect**

If you want to see the colors changing in the 3D Viewport, the display mode must be set to Rendered

Comment: To avoid having all your color ramp segments all squished together like that, don't divide by such a big number - not entirely sure, but I don't think the age is related to the number of particles.

Comment: Greg, I edited my answer to reflect your point. Should we delete our comments now since they would no longer make sense to future readers?

Comment: Sure, but one question - what is the lifetime of your particles set to?

Comment: Greg, it's set to 200. (I updated my answer to have that too)

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you mean change color over lifetime.

The problem with your node setup is simple to fix. Simply use the *Age* output instead of the *Index* output.

[image]   [image]

Comment: This method you describe here makes each particle change color over time, which is indeed a neat trick to know. 

However, if the Index value is used, it causes each particle to remain the same color throughout it's lifetime, but each particle is a slightly different color from the last one.

Comment: Apparently this only works with cycles, not Eevee. Any way to create the same effect in Eevee?