# Shooting Star blender render

Tags: particles

How i can do this in blender render...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NATgpZNYPSY

my particles go all crazy,

I have a empty that is the father of the star and planes that drop particles that makesthe tail of the star... following a path... but the tail of the shooting star is baaaad 
its posible to do this in blender?

Thks for ur help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: final]

### Particles settings:

In this example **Particles Emitter** is small **IcoSphere** following spiral **Curve**.

[image: emitter]

**Brownian** - will scatter particles.

**Damp** - will keep them together.

**Gravity** - well, will make them less influenced by gravity :)

**IcoSphere.001** - is our Particle Object.

Try them out to get desired result. 
(Constant rewinding video on YouTube is not my strong side.)

### Particle Object material:

[image: material]

To the **Particle Object** (in this case **IcoSphere.001**) you will want to assign **Particle Info** node and change color of them by their **Age**, or read more here: [How do I get particles to change color over time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/how-do-i-get-particles-to-change-color-over-time)

**Math** node > **Divide** allows you to change how quickly this change will be and **ColorRamp** gives you colors.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: THKS :) a make some changes. you put the material in cycle. I change the  sphere for only 1 vertex and put it halo size .040 and now its a tiny point and now i can render it with blenderrender and not cyles

Comment: I didn't knew that you were making it with Blender Render, but I'm glad you've worked it out.

Comment: :) its ok, no problem. thks