# How to make particles change colour over time in Eeevee?

Tags: materials, particles, eevee-render-engine

I just started tinkering with Blender (specifically 2.8) for the first time ever, and I've been looking up old tutorials on particles and how to change their colors over time, but I'm stuck on the colurs in the ColorRamp just sticking to one. I've been using Eevee to render.

[image: particles and material nodes in blender]

And here is the effect I'd like to make, except the blue particles turn to another color:
https://gyazo.com/868e518fb69b1910f22e282557ecea6f

Comment: Does this answer help your question?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/how-do-i-get-particles-to-change-color-over-time

Answer (score 0):

I know of two ways of doing it.
A: Add a "time node" using animation nodes, and point in "frame" to some math node then to "color"

B: Use Key Frames on the Color ramp. Click on the first color, set to the frame you want that color to be, in the shader, mouse over the color bar, press I.  Change frame, change color ramp color, mouse over color bar, press I.

NOTE: This changes *all* the particles color at once.
Note 2: The color ramp, as you have it, won't show up in Eevee, but will in Cycles.

This is similar to: [How do I get particles to change color over time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/how-do-i-get-particles-to-change-color-over-time)