# Problem with particle object with changing colors depending on location or age, but particle generator doesn't change

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

I'm trying to use the color ramp to change the particle colors over time, but i realize that even if the object I assigned as a particle changes its color the particle has a fixed gradient that is not dependant on the material of this particle I used.

Video: https://i.imgur.com/6QsxFmd.mp4

Here are all the node combinations I tried to use

[image]

And i also tried the nodes suggested on these answers: [How do I get particles to change color over time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/how-do-i-get-particles-to-change-color-over-time)

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've to test it with a mix node combining an emission node and a transparency node to see if it works but the particle system appears to be semi independent from the particle object material.

Here's my blender file, but it's basically what I show here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tm7p1jWl4y5eQ-CQa0_qdG7eircHN4uY

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is particles get a darker shade of blue and more transparent the older they get ?

Comment: I want the particles to get another shade of color with time or distance traveled and on top of that I want them to ease out slowly become transparent. Particles dissapear abruptly instead of slowly fading and that makes that trail effect I'm trying to create really blocky. Is it possible to get both effects? In any case, I can't even apply a radient to my trail of particles effectively...